# Make custom RatingBar on Android that color will be change when RatingBar not clicked

Tags: android, kotlin, ratingbar

How can i implement RatingBar like this image. When RatingBar not clicked, the color will be change to red.

[image: Rating Bar Image]

This is my code

```
<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/rate_star_location"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="?android:ratingBarStyleSmall"
    android:progressBackgroundTint="@color/grey"
    android:progressTint="#F9A825"
    android:isIndicator="false"
    android:rating="0"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:stepSize="1"/>
```

Comment: Please share the code of what you have tried so far

Comment: Okay, i have updated my question, and add my code